# Calling UIViewController method from within contained object

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, model-view-controller, uiviewcontroller

Suppose I have several objects (models) that belong to a UIViewController.  When one of the models changes or does something, I want it to notify the UIViewController so that the view can update immediately, or perform some animation in response.

How do I do this?  Specifically,

(1.) How do the individual objects know about the ViewController?  If I store a pointer to the ViewController inside each object, then I introduce a cyclical reference where a ViewController refers to children that refer to ViewController.

(2.) Even with a weak pointer, the model objects themselves don't know which view inside the ViewController corresponds to itself.  For example, say there are 10 views and 10 models. The models aren't coupled with the views (i.e. each model has a view that represents it in the array of 10, but the index isn't always the same, since the user is constantly switching them around, so while the models have a stable index 0...9, the view representing model 0 could be at index 1, or later at index 2, 3, ..., 9), so when a model updates, it needs to tell the ViewController somehow which of the 10 views represents it, except it doesn't know. So the ViewController in turn can't know which View to update.

I should add that my current code just gives each model object a pointer to its corresponding View, so that it doesn't need to go through the ViewController to access the correct View and update its contents.  But this would seem to violate MVC, so I'm trying to correct my code and realized I don't know how in this particular situation.

Sorry if that is confusing. I'll update the question if anything is unclear. 
EDIT: Updated with more concrete example code.

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<ProfileViewControllerDelegate>
{
    BattleModel* battle;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) BattleModel* battle;

@property (nonatomic, weak) NSArray* heroPersons; // Person objects
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSArray* villainPersons; // Person objects

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutletCollection(PersonImageView) NSArray* villainImages;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutletCollection(HealthBarView) NSArray* villainHealthBars;

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutletCollection(PersonImageView) NSArray* heroImages;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutletCollection(HealthBarView) NSArray* heroHealthBars;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView* reporter;
```

That describes the ViewController Interface.  Now, each Person class handles modification of the Person, in addition to how the Person reacts to attacks.

```
@interface Person : NSObject
{
    __weak Profile* profile;
    __weak PersonImageView* personImg;
    __weak BattleModel* currentBattle;
    Reaction* currentReaction;
}
// Reaction happens in the following methods:
-(BOOL) targetedFoeWithMove:(SelectedMove*)selMove log:(UITextView*)reporter;
-(BOOL) wasTargetedByMove:(SelectedMove*)selMove log:(UITextView*)reporter;
-(void) hitFoeWithMove:(SelectedMove*)selMove log:(UITextView*)reporter;
-(void) wasHitByMove:(SelectedMove*)selMove log:(UITextView*)reporter;
```

As you can see, I currently violate MVC because the reporter is passed into the model Person, and also a pointer to the personImg, which the VC should handle. Anyways, as the battle happens, the Reaction* is queried inside the various targeted, hit routines, and that's where modifications happen, and the reporter is notified. Notice how the Person has NO IDEA whatsoever which index its corresponding PersonView is occupying in the grand scheme UIViewController, so when currentReaction triggers in some deep routine, and passes up the data, the ViewController has no idea which UIView to update. It knew at one point (when the Person was created), but the heroImages and villainImages array gets shifted around a lot (even switching sides if one Person goes from hero to villain), so the index it had at birth isn't the index it necessarily has at the point when a Reaction triggers and needs to update the PersonImageView. That's a bit of an annoyance, so I might need to have data passed back up to the UIViewController, telling it which PersonImageView just underwent a Reaction (how would I do that?).

Here is a sample Reaction, just for completeness and helping you understand the system:

```
-(void) wasHitByMove:(SelectedMove*)selMove log:(UITextView*)reporter
{
    [self.currentReaction personWasHitByMove:selMove inBattle:self.currentBattle log:reporter];
}
```

And depending on if the Reaction is relevant (there are several subclasses of Reaction that do different things), a modification like "loseLife:(int)life" is called through a Person property setter, and that's when I need the report/animation to be bubbled up to the VC. Right now, the erroneous code (bad design) is simply going directly to the personImg for the animation, then the reporter for the textual notification. I realize this is bad design, which is why I'm here, but it isn't as simple as telling the VC through a callback, "(BOOL) Hey, something happened to me." because which PersonImageView is "me"? How does the ViewController, in the middle of its own method executing the logic of the battle, know to respond immediately to the callback? How is the callback even made? (Re: Delegates. So attach the delegate protocol to Person, PersonImageView, and UIViewController? And since they all follow the protocol, then they can interpret the common message through the protocol method?)

I also looked in NSNotification but find that too complicated for this purpose; it seems like it's more of a passive Observer type of thing, where in my application, when a Reaction triggers, I need the UIViewController to *immediately* update the screen with UITextView text + PersonImageView animations. Immediately in the sense that before the Reaction can trigger again, the animation needs to happen, as it could involve the PersonImageView recoiling, or falling down, or changing appearance. It isn't a real-time game, but the next attack will have already been queued and will be coming momentarily after the one before has triggered the currentReaction, so any kind of delay or passive observation might be bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegates.

Suppose you have a view with a button.  Give it a protocol:

```
@protocol MyButtonViewDelegate
@required
- (void)buttonPressed;
@end
```

Now your view with a button has a property like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSObject<MyButtonViewDelegate> *delegate;
```

Which is its reference to the view controller.

The view with a button's class will have a method like this which is hooked up to the button:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self.delegate buttonPressed];
}
```

Your view control conforms to the `MyButtonViewDelegate` protocol and sets itself as the delegate to the view.  It then implements the method `buttonPressed`:

```
- (void)buttonPressed {
    // do whatever you want to do when that button was pressed
}
```

---

If you need to pass a reference to the view in this method, you can do that too:

```
@protocol MyViewDelegate
@required
- (void)someMethod:(id)sender;
@end
```

Then:

```
- (IBAction)someUserInteractionWithView {
    [self.delegate someMethod:self];
}
```

The delegate then implements the method from the protocol:

```
- (void)someMethod:(id)sender {
    // sender is a reference to the view which called this method on delegate
}
```

---

You can write a protocol method to send as many arguments as you want.  You can even have these methods return values that you make use of:

```
@protocol MyResizableViewProtocol
@required
- (CGRect)newSizeForResizableView:(MyResizableView*)resizableView;
@end
```

Something within the view class triggers this method to be called on the delegate and request a new size.  The delegate implements this method:

```
- (CGRect)newSizeForResizableView:(MyResizableView*)resizableView {
    return CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f, 400.0f);
}
```

And the resizable view makes use of the method as such:

```
- (void)timeToResize {
    self.frame = [self.delegate newSizeForResizableView:self];
}
```

---

As far as I'm concerned, understanding protocols and delegates is one of the more important aspects of iOS development.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the proposal! Two things: (1.) I understand your code, but where does it go? As in, when you said to give "it" a protocol, do I write that in the View class, the ViewController class, or the object class? Please say in which files/classes the other snippets go, too; (2.) In my case, there is actually no user interaction, so not sure if I can use (IBAction). My objects are Persons, each with a Reaction. As a turn unfolds, Persons throw Attacks at each other, and when an Attack hits, it may provoke a Reaction, which I then want the corresponding PersonView to scroll via text.

Comment: ...so each Person has a "personWasTargeted" or "personWasHit" method, which triggers relevant Reaction objects. The Reaction object does things to the Person, modifies some data values, then needs to go all the way up the chain to the UIViewController that contains the Person objects, so it can tell the order-constantly-changing PersonViews, scroll text in UITextView etc. In this case, who needs to define the protocol, and who becomes the delegate? The UIViewController? The PersonView? UITextView? The Person? The Reaction?

Comment: You don't have to necessarily trigger this stuff via `IBAction` methods.  It's just the example I used as it's pretty common to need this functionality (and because based on my understand of your question, it's what I thought you needed).

Comment: The protocol should be declared on the view's `.h` file (outside the `@interface`).  The view's `.h` should be imported by the View Controller.  The View Controller should conform to the protocol: `YourVC : UIViewController <SomeViewProtocol>`.  The View should have a `delegate` property that is marked as conforming to this protocol.  If you need some more explanation, try to find me here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15942/nschat

Comment: I agree that delegates in general are the way to go, so I appreciate your sample code and help, but where my issue differs from the View delegate is that most of the action is happening deep in the Model (from MVC), not the View, and I somehow need that deeply nested action to be communicated to the View. I think a 3rd party "manager" or "delegate" object is generally the way, but I am still unfamiliar with how to get Model children to communicate to VC, telling it to "change view X." Who gets the delegate, defines the methods/protocol, etc? Not the View, because it knows nothing about Model.

Comment: @Cindeselia This would be easier to explain in chat. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15942/nschat The view doesn't "get the delegate".  It does define the protocol, however it does not define the methods that the protocol defines.  The view controller delegates the view.  All the view does is say "Hey, this happened!  I need someone to respond to it because I don't know what to do!" It tells this to the delegate who then replies to it.  If you could simplify your scenario down to its absolute basic basics, I could potentially show you some sample code that applies directly to your scenario

Comment: Thanks, nhgrif! The link took me to a chat room in which I couldn't talk because of permissions. I guess you have to be there.. Either way, I'll continue to try to catch you.. It's night here in JPN.

Comment: @Cindeselia, you have to request write permission to use most of StackOverflow's chats.

Comment: What is write permission, and how do I request it?

Comment: What is confusing me is that your example is of a View. Can I put the delegate in my model, and its submodels, ... all the way down to a very deeply nested sub-sub-sub object in the model?  My View is just a dumb display, it doesn't need to respond to user interaction.  My Model, on the other hand, is always changing at a moment's notice, but can I set the VC to be the Model's delegate, set the Model to be the subModel's delegate, set the subModel to be the subsubModel's delegate, ..., all the way down until the deeply nested subsubsubModel can get its message to the VC?

Comment: In short, yes.  I mean, you're already using protocols.  Your example `ViewController` is listed as conforming to the `ProfileViewControllerDelegate` protocol.  Consider `TableViewDataSource` is also a protocol.  It's one of two protocols that control a tableview.  Objects that conform to the data source protocol are the ones that tell the table what to display.  The `@protocol` itself is found with the `UITableView` because the view defines what methods its data source needs to implement in order to fill it with information, put some OTHER class is the one that conforms to the protocol and

Comment: is actually implementing the methods.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this. One way is by notifications. Have your models send out notifications when these interesting events happen. Your view controller can then sign up to receive these notifications and act accordingly.

In each model, do something like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"somethingInModel3" object:self];
```

In the view controller, do something like this in `init` or `viewDidLoad`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                     selector:@selector(handleModel3Event:)        
                                         name:@"somethingInModel3" 
                                       object:nil];
```

The selector specifies the method that will handle the notification. You need to write that method as appropriate.

You'll also need to put (e.g., in `dealloc` in the view controller):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Does NSNotification force the ViewController to act immediately? Do I need to pass the NotificationCenter class to each of the object's individual Reactions (see newly posted code)? I must admit I am hesitant because it seems like the Notification send time and actual reaction are sort of decoupled, i.e. they don't happen one after the other. Is that a misconception, what classes should I use and who gets what? Sorry for being vague, just that the biggest struggle here is knowing what each class involved needs to have object-wise. I can figure out API and the rest.

Comment: NSNotification is like a radio station, and it is up to the ViewController how it wishes to respond. Basically, you set the ViewController up to call a method as soon as it gets notified. See http://www.idev101.com/code/Cocoa/Notifications.html for more details, for example. Will edit the answer to give more details.

Comment: Thank you for linking me to that introduction; I read everything. Only question is, how rapid can I expect the response to be in practice?  So my VC declares a NSNotificationCenter, signs up to receive ("observe") notifications from my ever-changing Models, and then just pass pointers to each Model for methods that may trigger change? When Model X2 changes, and it posts a notification via that function, does the VC get it immediately (as fast as calling a function and [view setNeedsDisplay]), provided nothing on the thread is blocking?

Comment: I haven't had to worry about exact response times, so I don't know. Perhaps you could test/try/measure and see how it compares with other ways?

Answer (score 1):

Bocks are a great way to implement callbacks in objective-c. [Here is a link to Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html). Apple already implements blocks all over their APIs with `NSOperationQueue`, `NSOperation`, view animation, and many others. Check out this [article about communication patterns](http://www.objc.io/issue-7/communication-patterns.html) in iOS, it explains the right circumstances for using delegation, blocks, notifications, and others.